# Setting overflow-y causes overflow-x to change as well

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

When I set `overflow-y` on a block, it seems to be affecting the `overflow-x` property. I've made a [JSFiddle with an example of this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/sgjennings/7fNhx/). It seems to be happening in all browsers, so I think I'm missing something that should be obvious.

I have two non-overlapping blocks (blue and green) along with a third block (red) with the following requirements:

- The blue and red blocks are adjacent
- The red block is contained in the blue block, but it overlaps the green block
- The blue block must allow vertical scrolling, but not horizontal scrolling

However, if I set `overflow-x: visible` so the red block overlaps to the right, instead it behaves as though I set it to `scroll`. However, if I remove the `overflow-y` property or set it to `visible`, the red block behaves as I expect.

I do need vertical scrolling, so I'm at a loss for what to do.

With the code below

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="floater"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc; border: solid 5px black;
}
#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;    /** REMOVING THIS CHANGES THE RESULT **/
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
#floater {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px; top: 30px; height: 40px; width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jwXaj/ but the `#floater` block needs to be a sibling of the `#left` and `#right` blocks.

Comment: I have this http://jsfiddle.net/7fNhx/1/ ...not sure what u try to achieve tho

Comment: @MarcAudet The #floater can't be a sibling because in the page where I'm actually having the problem, '#left' is actually a class and there are many of them, each with their own floater.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See: [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

> If you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and
>   something other than visible for the other, the visible value is
>   interpreted as auto.

Comment: Found this looking to see if the standard had changed lately, nope. Oddly though some of our stuff just broke recently where we were setting overflow-x and not overflow-y. So some browser interpretations must have changed...